# How can i call a controller method or action from route setupController in ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js

Im trying to call a controller action from the route.

```
setupController(controller, model) {


        controller.set('model', model);

        //controller.send('showInvite');
        controller.send('switchTabByName',model.get('name'));


        if(!this.get('state.user.hasCopiedInviteLink')) {
            controller.send('showInvite');
        }
```

but i cant i get "publish.continue Nothing handled the action 'switchTabByName'."

ive tried to call a method directly without an action but didn't worked either. How can i achieve this?

This is my actions block in the controller

```
actions: {

        switchTabByName(tabName){
                //console.log('Will switch to tab ',tabName);
                let tab = this.get('tabs').find((item)=> {return item.get('name')===tabName; } );
                this.switchTab(tab);

        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I auto-answer my question, anyway im not completely satisifed so I ended up doing this

```
this.controllerFor('publish').send('switchTabByName',model.get('name'));
```

i dont understand why this works and not the later. but this worked so if anybody runs to the same problem. hope this helps

Comment: Tried a similar test case in ember-twiddle and it worked fine for me. I did come up with this kind of issue once when using single template and controller for three different routes. Is this the scenario for you?

Comment: Similar yes, im using a custom tab component, and wanted to make a route that will set a user in a certain tab with the model as representation of the state